# How to understand Gen. 12:5–6 with Rashi

Tags: rashi, parashat-lech-lecha

[*B'reshis* 12:5](http://chabad.org/8176#showrashi=true&v=5):

> ‏…וַיֵּצְאוּ לָלֶכֶת אַרְצָה כְּנַעַן / …and they left to go to the land of Canaan
>   וַיָּבֹאוּ אַרְצָה כְּנָעַן.‏ / and they went in<sup>[1]</sup> to the land of Canaan.

And verse 6:

> וַיַּעֲבֹר אַבְרָם בָּאָרֶץ / And Abram passed in the land
>   עַד מְקוֹם שְׁכֶם…‏ / until the site of Shechem…

<sup>[1]</sup> (The word "בָּא" AFAIK generally means "enter" or "go in" in *Chumash*. See e.g. *B'reshis* 7:1.)

*Rashi* comments on "וַיַּעֲבֹר אַבְרָם בָּאָרֶץ / And Abram passed in the land" that it means

> נכנס לתוכה / he entered its inside.

(Commentaries on *Rashi* (*Mizrachi*, *Gur Arye*, *Sifse Chachamim*) note that *Rashi* means to inform us that "וַיַּעֲבֹר אַבְרָם בָּאָרֶץ" does *not* mean that Abram passed through the entire land, exiting its far end.)

I'm having trouble understanding these verses with *Rashi*'s commentary. Here are some possibilities:

1. Verse 5 means "they came to the land", i.e. to its border, but didn't enter it. In verse 6, "נכנס" means "he crossed the border". The question on this is why *Rashi* felt compelled to explain the verses this way. One could more easily AFAICT read verse 5 as saying Abram entered the land and verse 6 as saying he then proceeded partway through the land (not entering it), as in option 3, below.
2. Verse 5 means "they entered the land" and, in verse 6, "נכנס" means the same: it's repeating itself. The question on this is why repeat.
3. Verse 5 means "they entered the land" and, in verse 6, "נכנס לתוכה" means "he proceeded further, more deeply, into the land". The question on this why *Rashi* used a word, "נכנס", that typically AFAIK means "entered". (Or doesn't it?)
4. Or perhaps there's another explanation.

I'd appreciate any insight.